# VS2015 Compile-time error when I write an header and a source file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I have a problem with VS2015. When I write a header and then I write its source file and put them in the project, when I try to compile it gives me a lot of errors but, if I put everything in the main file, it works perfectly.

Do I miss something?

I'm posting header and source file.

Thanks!

Header.h:

```
    #pragma once

class Money
{
private:
    int dollar;
    long int cents;
public:
    Money();
    Money(int d, long int c);
    int f_dollar() const { return dollar; }
    int f_cents() const { return cents; }
    Money round_cent(Money& m);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Money& m);
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Money& m);
```

Header.cpp:

```
#include "Header.h"
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

Money::Money()
    :dollar{ 0 }, cents{ 0 } {};
Money::Money(int d, long int c)
    :dollar{ d }, cents{ c } {};

Money Money::round_cent(Money& m)
{
    int last_digit = m.cents % 10;
    int diff = 10;
    if (last_digit >= 5)
    {
        diff -= last_digit;
        return Money(m.dollar, m.cents + diff);
    }
    if (last_digit < 5) return Money(m.dollar, m.cents - last_digit);
}

istream& operator>>(istream& is, Money& m)
{
    int dollar;
    long int cents;
    cout << "Type dollars amount: $" << endl;
    is >> dollar;
    is.ignore(10, '.');
    is >> cents;
    if (!is) return is;

    m = Money(dollar, cents);

    return is;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Money& m)
{
    return os << "We have " << m.f_dollar() << "." << m.f_cents()
        << " rounded." << endl;
}
```

Money.cpp:

```
// Money.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include "Header.h"


int main()
{
    Money m;
    cin >> m;
    m = m.round_cent(m);
    cout << m;

    return 0;
}
```

Errors:

```
Severity    Code    Source  Description Project File    Line
Error   C2146   Build   syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'round_cent'    Money   c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp  10
Error   C2143   Build   syntax error: missing ';' before '{'    Money   c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp  11
Error   C2143   Build   syntax error: missing ';' before '{'    Money   c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp  38
Error   C2143   Build   syntax error: missing ';' before '&'    Money   c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp  22
Error   C2143   Build   syntax error: missing ';' before '&'    Money   c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp  37
Error   C2059   Build   syntax error: 'const'   Money   c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp  37
Error   C4430   Build   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Money c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp    6
Error   C4430   Build   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Money c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp    8
Error   C4430   Build   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Money c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp    10
Error   C4430   Build   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Money c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp    22
Error   C4430   Build   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Money c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp    37
Error   C2563   Build   mismatch in formal parameter list   Money   c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp  22
Error   C2447   Build   '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)   Money   c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp  11
Error   C2447   Build   '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)   Money   c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp  38
Error   C2065   Build   'os': undeclared identifier Money   c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp  37
Error   C2473   Build   'operator >>': looks like a function definition, but there is no parameter list.    Money c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp    22
Error   C2365   Build   'Money': redefinition; previous definition was 'function'   Money c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp    10
Error   C2653   Build   'Money': is not a class or namespace name   Money   c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp  5
Error   C2653   Build   'Money': is not a class or namespace name   Money   c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp  7
Error   C2653   Build   'Money': is not a class or namespace name   Money   c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp  10
Warning C4508   Build   'Money': function should return a value; 'void' return type assumed Money c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp    6
Warning C4508   Build   'Money': function should return a value; 'void' return type assumed Money c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp    8
Error   C2550   Build   'Money': constructor initializer lists are only allowed on constructor definitions  Money c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp    6
Error   C2550   Build   'Money': constructor initializer lists are only allowed on constructor definitions  Money c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp    8
Error   C2065   Build   'm': undeclared identifier  Money   c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp  22
Error   C2065   Build   'is': undeclared identifier Money   c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp  22
Error   C2448   Build   '>>': function-style initializer appears to be a function definition    Money c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp    23
Warning C4627   Build   '#include "std_lib_facilities.h"': skipped when looking for precompiled header use  Money c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp    2
Warning C4627   Build   '#include "Header.h"': skipped when looking for precompiled header use  Money c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\money\money\header.cpp    1
```

It seem that it skips Header.h but I do not know why.

Thank you.

Comment: That error message is terrifying. It would be very nice if you could try to find relevant stuff in there.

Comment: Yep it is! It is very strange because, as I said, if I put all in the main cpp file it perfectly runs. I need to improve quite a lot the code then I cannot put all staff in there!

Comment: In Visual Studio, .CPP files should start with `#include "stdafx.h"`, the precompiled header, as the first line. Also you are using `cout` and various classes without including `iostream` and other relevant headers. Unless they are in `std_lib_facilities.h`.

Comment: As a general practice, your user-defined header files should appear after the system-defined header files.

Comment: I use Stroustrup's header that includes <iostream> and the other relevant headers. For what regards "stdafx.h" it is already on top in main cpp file and even if I put it on top in Header.cpp it does still not work. I have tried to reset settings too but without any result.

Comment: @unxnut You were right! In Header.cpp file once I've put `#include "Header.h"` after `#include "stdafx.h"` and `#include "std_lib_facilities.h"` it well compiled.
Many thanks!

Comment: #include "stdafx.h" needs to be first, anything before it is ignored.

Comment: @MarianSpanik got it, thanks!

Comment: @Leonardo Urbano You don't need to put semicolons after the money class constructors in the source file.

Comment: @JamesMoore ok thank you! I will not put them anymore then!

Answer (score 1):

If your project is configured to use precompiled headers (default), you need to include the stdafx.h file as the first #include from each .cpp file in the project.

So to fix your specific scenario, either move the #include "stdafx.h" line in your Header.cpp file up to the top, or configure the project not to use precompiled headers.

Comment: Well spotted. Funny thing that `stdafx.h` - the compiler ignore everything until it finds that include, irrespective of syntax errors or otherwise.